# How to generalize this for loop for any lenght?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I want to generalize this in python for any "pos" length

```py
for a in range(pos[0]):
    for b in range(pos[1]):
        for c in range(pos[2]):
            for d in range(pos[3]):
                for e in range(pos[4]):
                    for f in range(pos[5]):     
                        neighbours.append([a, b, c, d, e, f])
```

I want to gather all the neighbours of my position in 6 dimensions. Neighbours are all combinations of `x-1`, `x` and `x+1` for all coordinates. So I have to gather 3^dim -1 neighbours. `pos` is a {dim} length list with positions for all coordinatess. `dx` is discretization length. As you can see all loops are the same except for an increasing index in `pos`, so I want to generalize that, if possible.

```py
for a in range(pos[0]- self.dx, pos[0]+2*self.dx, self.dx):
    for b in range(pos[1]- self.dx, pos[1]+2*self.dx, self.dx):
        for c in range(pos[2]- self.dx, pos[2]+2*self.dx, self.dx):
            for d in range(pos[3]- self.dx, pos[3]+2*self.dx, self.dx):
                for e in range(pos[4]- self.dx, pos[4]+2*self.dx, self.dx):
                    for f in range(pos[5]- self.dx, pos[5]+2*self.dx, self.dx):     
                        neighbours.append([a, b, c, d, e, f])
```

Comment: `for item in pos:`

Comment: Look up the `intertools` package, specifically the `product` method applied to a list of items.  The syntax is something like `neighbours = list(product(pos*))`

Comment: Typo: `itertools`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it easily using recursion:

```
def combinations(pos, acc=[[]] * 3):
    if len(pos) == 0:
        return a    Cloud

    Amazon announced a $250 million venture fund to invest in Indian startups cc
    else:
        return combinations(pos[1:],
                            acc = \
                            [x + [y] for x in acc for y in pos[0]])
```

Test it by:

```
combinations([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h']])
```

Which gives:

```
[['a', 'd', 'f'],
 ['a', 'd', 'g'],
 ['a', 'd', 'h'],
 ['a', 'e', 'f'],
 ['a', 'e', 'g'],
 ['a', 'e', 'h'],
 ['b', 'd', 'f'],
 ['b', 'd', 'g'],
 ...
  ['a', 'd', 'f'],
 ['a', 'd', 'g'],
 ['a', 'd', 'h'],
 ['a', 'e', 'f'],
 ['a', 'e', 'g'],
 ['a', 'e', 'h'],
 ['b', 'd', 'f'],
 ['b', 'd', 'g'],
 ['b', 'd', 'h'],
 ['b', 'e', 'f'],
 ['b', 'e', 'g'],
 ['b', 'e', 'h'],
 ['c', 'd', 'f'],
 ['c', 'd', 'g'],
 ['c', 'd', 'h'],
 ['c', 'e', 'f'],
 ['c', 'e', 'g'],
 ['c', 'e', 'h']]
```

To remove duplicates, put a `list(set())` around the result, or if you want to keep the order:

```
result_list_unique = []
for x in result_list:
    if x not in result_list_unique:
        result_list_unique.append(x)
```

and use `result_list_unique`

Comment: ok, i tried this and works very well, except it also returns some of the combinations more than once. thanks for your help

Comment: in that case just put a `list(set())` around the result - to make it unique

Comment: if it helped you please choose it as answer.